# SAXparser method's arguments

Tags: java, handler, sax, saxparser

I am using a method to use `SAXparser` which uses an extended version of the `defaulthandler`. as a result, when trying to use `parser` method with `inputstream` and the extended `defaulthandler` arguments, it gives an error saying that it can not find a suitable method for such arguments. in case of being have to use those arguments, how can I solve it?

The method that extends `defaulthandler`:

```
            static private class newConfigHandler extends DefaultHandler   {
              ...

    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI,String localName, String rawName) throws SAXException {
  ....
    }
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        ....   
         }
                                                                 }
```

the error happens in third line of below code:

```
        sParser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
        newHandler = new newConfigHandler();
        URL u;
        sParser.parse(u.openStream(),newHandler);
```

Comment: Can you please add the error stack as well?

Comment: @potame it is not an exception or runtime error, hence there is no such a thing

Comment: It should work fine. Do you have access to the APIs in your classpath?

Comment: @potame there are other APIs and only for this one it has an error. it is because that parser method needs defaulthandler type but it gets newHandler. how to fix it?